# Resizing of div based on the width of the screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have the following code. Why is the size of the div not adjusting when I reduce the width of the screen? What I'm trying to achieve is, that the size of the div has to reduce proportionally when the width of the screen is reduced so that the div doesn't look gigantic. I tried converting the width and height to vh and percentages but it's not working

```css
.sign_logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6.2rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgb(200, 0, 50);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sign_logo">
  <a>Register</a>
</div>
```

Comment: “I tried converting width and height to vh….” did you mean this? vh is viewport height unit. Did you use vw for the width unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you intend to do, you are using the wrong kind of units: Use `vw` and `vh` instead of `rem`, those are relative to width and height of the viewport.

And add `display: flex;` to center the content in your div, otherwise `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` won't have any effect.

```css
.sign_logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgb(200, 0, 50);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5vw;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sign_logo">
  <a>Register</a>
</div>
```